# Using \tcbhighmath for just one aligned equation in the align* environment?

Tags: equations, tcolorbox

I'm trying to figure out how to just put a stylized box using `\tcbhighmath` in only one equation in a set within the `align*` environment. So for example:

```
\begin{align*}
   x &= 2 + y \\
   y &= 1 + z \\
   z &= 3 + x
\end{align*}
```

I only want a box around the last equation: z = 3 + x.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot span a box across two `align` columns directly, but here's a workaround to get the desired result.

`align` uses two passes to typeset the equations: the first one measures the heights/widths of all components, the second pass actually typesets them. We define a new command `\mathbox{...&...}` that collects the left and right part of the equation. On the measuring pass (`\ifmeasuring@` is true) we normally set the column text to get the correct widths.

The second pass sets an zero-width `\tcbhighmath` box with the columns' text in it, additionally shifted to the left by the sum of the widths of the left column's text plus several parameters of the box style (inner margin, rule width etc.), such that the equal sign is aligned with the ones outside of the box. The result is basically an empty right column with the box in the left column overlapping both columns.

Minimal example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter

\def\mathbox#1{\mathbox@#1\@end}
\def\mathbox@#1&#2\@end{%
    \ifmeasuring@
        #1%
    \else
        \begingroup
        \setbox0=\hbox{$\displaystyle#1$}%
        \dimen0=\dimexpr\wd0+\kvtcb@left@rule+\kvtcb@leftupper
                            +\kvtcb@boxsep+\kvtcb@bbleft\relax
        \hskip-\dimen0\relax
        \mathrlap{\tcbhighmath{\displaystyle#1 #2}}%
        \hskip\dimen0\relax
        \endgroup
    \fi
    &
    \ifmeasuring@
        #2%
    \fi
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
   x &= 2 + y \\
   y &= 1 + z \\
   z &= 3 + x
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
   x &= 2 + y \\
   y &= 1 + z \\
   \mathbox{z &= 3 + x}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

outputs

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
highlight math/.append style={
        grow to left by =4.25mm,}
}
  \let\boxed=\tcbhighmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
   x &= 2 + y \\
   y &= 1 + z \\
   \Aboxed{z &= 3 + x}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Some explanation**

The `mathtools` package provides the `\Aboxed` command that can be used like this:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
...
\begin{align*}
   x &= 2 + y \\
   y &= 1 + z \\
   \Aboxed{z &= 3 + x}
\end{align*}
```

to produce somme thing like this:

[image]

Accordingly to the `mathtools` manual : `internally \Aboxed does use \boxed` .

To let the `\Aboxed` command use the `\tcbhighmath` box we redefine the `\boxed` command with `\let\boxed\tcbhightmath`  and we get:

[image]

AS can be seen we need to adjust the position of the box so we add the  `grow to left by = <some distance>` option to the `highlight math` style : `\tcbset{highlight math/.append style={grow to left by =4.25mm,}}`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `hf-tikz`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,hf-tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
   x &= 2 + y \\
   y &= 1 + z \\
   \tikzmarkin{a}z &= 3 + x\tikzmarkend{a}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The argument to `\tikzmarkin` and `\tikzmarkend` should be a unique string.

[image]